# Character Repetition

Tags: c#, algorithm, character, repeat

I am writing a simple program to calculate the repetition of characters in a string sequence. The program I have for now is as below, but I am looking to see if it can be optimized any further. I believe the program right now is O(n) worst case time and I would like to see if there is something that can give me O(log n) running time.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Algos
{
    class CharacterRepitition
    {
        private char[] checkStringArray;
        private bool[] discovered;

        public CharacterRepitition(string toCheck)
        {
                checkStringArray= toCheck.ToCharArray();           
                discovered= new bool[checkStringArray.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < checkStringArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    discovered[i] = false;
                }
        }

        public void CheckRepetitions()
        {
            int charIndex=0;
            Dictionary<char, int> repetitions = new Dictionary<char, int>();
            while (charIndex < checkStringArray.Length)
            {
                int count = 0;

                if(discovered[charIndex].Equals(false))
                {
                    count = RunThroughTheString(charIndex, checkStringArray);
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        repetitions.Add(checkStringArray[charIndex], count+1);
                    }
                }
                charIndex++;
            }

            if (repetitions.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nNo characters repeated.");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int> result in repetitions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n'"+ result.Key + "' is present: " + result.Value + " times.");
                }
            }
        }

        private int RunThroughTheString(int currentCharIndex, char[] checkStringArray)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < checkStringArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (checkStringArray[currentCharIndex].Equals(checkStringArray[i]) && i !=currentCharIndex)
                {
                    counter++;
                    discovered[i] = true;
                }
            }
            return counter;
        }

    }
}
```

I know i can achieve this with LINQ as well. But that is not something I am looking for. Appreciate your help.

Comment: It _has_ to be `O(n)`, as one must go through each character. I don't see how you could even theoretically reduce that.

Comment: Only this code looks a bit above O(n) .. ? But I don't know how to refine that thought.

Comment: @Cicada could you let me know what I can do to improve this code? Yes I can understand the logic behind O(n) running time.

Comment: It looks like your code is simply counting the number of each character in the string, but is scanning the string multiple times to do so - O(N log N) maybe?  Scan the string once and collect the results for O(N).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I read the question correctly, but would this work in you situation

```
    public void FindCharRepetitions(string toCheck)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        foreach (var chr in toCheck)
        {
            if (result.ContainsKey(chr))
            {
                result[chr]++;
                continue;
            }
            result.Add(chr, 1);
        }

       foreach (var item in result)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Char: {0}, Count: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Yes @sa_ddam213 ... My program was O(nlgn) as Corey pointed out... This is O(n) ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the number of different characters is known (say only A-Z) then the code could be like this:

```
int[] counters = new int['Z' - 'A' + 1];
foreach(char c in toCheck)
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        counters[c - 'A']++;
```